# WCF - EndpointNotFoundException when calling from another Web Application (WCF or REST API)

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, exception

recently I've met problem with EndpointNotFoundException when calling from another Web Application (WCF or REST API) in WCF.

I'm trying to connect to external WCF service which needs login and password identification (right now I'm working on test enviroment prepared by provider).

Then exception occours:

`There was no endpoint listening at https://xxx/yyy.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details`

This problem not occurs in Console Application - works smooth but only when I'm creating simple projects such as WCF or REST API.

```
<bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="custom">
          <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"
            requireDerivedKeys="true" includeTimestamp="true" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
            <localClientSettings detectReplays="false" />
            <localServiceSettings detectReplays="false" />
          </security>
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" />
          <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://uslugaterytws1test.stat.gov.pl/TerytWs1.svc"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="custom" contract="TerytWsTest.ITerytWs1"
        name="custom" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
```

```
TerytWs1Client tc = new TerytWs1Client();
tc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "TestPubliczny";
tc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "1234abcd";
var zalogowany = tc.CzyZalogowany();
```

As well I have tried:

```
try { 
var proxy = new ChannelFactory<TerytWsTest.ITerytWs1>("custom");
proxy.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "TestPubliczny";
proxy.Credentials.UserName.Password = "1234abcd";
var result = proxy.CreateChannel();
var test = result.CzyZalogowany();
} 
catch (Exception ex) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to make sure that your WCF service has been started, you can check whether the WCF service has been started through the browser:

[image]

Then you can call the WCF service by adding a service reference:

[image]

[image]

After clicking OK, it will automatically generate the proxy class, we can call the WCF service through the proxy class:

[image]

Comment: I starts and works normally except external WCF calling. Probably I've mentioned it above.

Comment: What does external call mean? Is it because the network is blocked?

Comment: Endpoint address you can try to use IP address.

Comment: External call means I've created WCF Service which Im running now on localhost which has external Connected Service reference `https://uslugaterytws1test.stat.gov.pl/wsdl/terytws1.wsdl` with login and pass which is mentioned above (it is test service so I'm not worried about that data). And with that I cant connect with SocketException and timeout (but from Console App template project I can so probably is something in web.config I assume).

Comment: CASE CLOSED. Problem was my company proxy to connect outside with Web service. So I've added proxy address and flags to <httpsTransport /> and everything works fine.